# Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data

Tags: android, kotlin, file, share, android-fileprovider

I am trying to share file downloaded by DownloadManager but FileProvider.getURIForFile returns exception
Failed to find configured root that contains Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.siliconmind.reportsystem.debug/files/Download/2024_03_17_22_report.pdf

I tried the following code but it keeps throwing exception
`val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(                 requireContext(),                 context?.applicationContext?.packageName + ".fileprovider",                File("file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.siliconmind.reportsystem.debug/files/Download/2024_03_17_22_report.pdf:)             )             val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)             intent.setType("*/*")             intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)             startActivity(intent)`

This is the provider_paths file
`<paths>     <external-files-path name="my_download" path="/"/> </paths>`

And in manifest file
        `<provider             android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"             android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"             android:exported="false"             android:grantUriPermissions="true">             <meta-data                 android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"                 android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />         </provider>`

Comment: Unreadable post. Please post code and xml in normal code blocks. Just look how others do it. Preserve the lines to make all readable.